# Convert integer to string in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to convert an integer (e.g. 20211008) to a string format (2021-10-08) to use as a primary key in a separate sub-query.
I have tried the following:

```sql
primary_key = cast(PARSE_DATETIME(cast(integer as VARCHAR),'yyyyMMdd') as date)
```

but receive an error: =' cannot be applied to varchar, date"

Comment: Is your intention to convert this integer date to a proper date type, or just a string date?  Note that you should probably be leaning towards the former option from a design point of view.

Comment: `select cast(PARSE_DATETIME(cast(20211008 as varchar),'yyyyMMdd') as date)` works like a charm for me. Can you please post a repro data?

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks! However, since I am looking to set the primary_key equal to this value I still get the error =' cannot be applied to varchar, date"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen keen to try either option but I agree that a proper date type would work best

Comment: And what is type of `primary_key`?

Comment: @GuruStron it is a string

Comment: Then why are you trying to assign date to it?